# Limit of rational function equal to Limit of Derivative

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, functions, polynomials

everyone. I have been thinking of this problem recently and am wondering if anyone is able to prove/disprove it:

Let $R$ be a rational function, that is let $R(x)=p(x)/q(x)$ where $p$ and $q$ are polynomials of degree > 0. Assume that at some point $x=a$, the function $R(x)$ is undefined (e.g. by division by zero): That is $R(a)$=undefined. Then
$$\lim_{x\to a}R(x)=\lim_{x\to a}R^*(x),$$
where $R^*(x)=p'(x)/q'(x)$, where $p'(x)$ and $q'(x)$ are the derivatives of the polynomials of $p$ and $q$ respectively.

Is this equation always true?

Comment: Maybe this is interesting for you:http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/122786/formula-for-calculating-residue-at-a-simple-pole

Comment: Sorry, I meant to add that deg p,q>0

Comment: Why the down vote ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it's not:

$$\lim_{x\to0}\frac1x\;\;\;\text{doesn't exist, yet}\;\;\lim_{x\to0}\frac01=0$$

**Added after comment below** . Still false:

$$\lim_{x\to0}x\frac{x-1}x\;\;\;\text{again doesn't exist, yet}\;\;\lim_{x\to0}\frac11=1$$

Comment: Sorry, I meant to add that deg p,q>0

Comment: @DanielePilkington-Scimone Still false. Read addition.

Comment: when you say lim(x to 0)1/x doesn't exist, isn't the limit equal to +infinity?

Comment: But then, why does it work in this example: say p(x)=(x-a)(x+a) and q(x)=(x-a). Then, lim(x approach a)(p(x)/q(x))=lim(x approach a)(p'(x)/q'(x)). Assume a is positive integer.

Comment: @DanielePilkington-Scimone No, when I say it doesn't exist I mean that: it is neither $\;\infty\;$ nor $\;-\infty\;$, as you can check evaluating the corresponding one-sided limits.

Comment: Actually I just found out the answer myself. Thank you for helping anyway

Comment: @DanielePilkington-Scimone "For helping *anyway*"? The above **is the correct answer** to what you asked, whether you got it from here or from somewhere else. There is no other "the answer" ...

Comment: I was being kind by saying thank you for helping me as in you showed me a counterexample and then talked to me in the chat. Next time, do you want me to say 'thanks for not helping me at all...